# How to DIAGNOSE Jenkins Agent jnlp connection 403 forbidden

Tags: jenkins

Some of our Jenkins agents on Windows connect via `-jnlpCredentials`:

```
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xms256m -Xmx2048m -jar "%BASE%\agent.jar" -noCertificateCheck 
  -jnlpUrl https://our-ciserver.org/jenkins/computer/bla/slave-agent.jnlp 
  -jnlpCredentials thejnlpuser:thesecret</arguments>
```

This used to work fine, but recently when restarting such a slave, it can no longer connect, reporting:

```
Failing to obtain https://our-ciserver.org/jenkins/computer/bla/slave-agent.jnlp
java.io.IOException: Failed to load https://our-ciserver.org/jenkins/computer/bla/slave-agent.jnlp: 403 Forbidden
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.parseJnlpArguments(Launcher.java:499)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:325)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:283)
Waiting 10 seconds before retry
```

The user `thejnlpuser` is a registered Jenkins user, and I can log in interactively for this user. Authentication is via the Active Directory Plugin.

Now, obviously, something is not working when Jenkins is validating this access -- but how do I find out what??

I tried fiddling with System Loggers at `/jenkins/log` loggers, adding logging for `hudson.plugins.active_directory` and some other trial and error.

But how can I get Jenkins to report what actually is going wrong here?

- How do I find which logger is relevant?
- How do I find which logging level is relevant?

Answer (score 1):

The error listed here is a `403 Forbidden` not a `401 Unauthorized` -- so looking for possible AD/rights problems will possibly not lead to a solution.

Diagnosing JNLP error should then go on to query the *actual* jnlp file URL with the credentials given, not just trying to log in:

This lead to the solution:  all was fine with the user, except that it's agent rights had been revoked in the rights matrix in the Jenkins settings, so surfing to the jnlp file immediately got a 403 Forbidden status with a *very* helpful page content that told that this user does not have the agent rights to GET the jnlp file.

To query the jnlp file, the user needs the following rights:

- Agent:Connect
- Agent:Disconnect (maybe; we set this anyway)
- Overall:Read (maybe; we set this anyway)

So the steps are:

- Open the actual URL with the actual credentials in the browser.
- Check the user rights
- Don't worry about the System Logs